# Liquibase & AWS Redshift: Cannot generate-changelog due to ERROR: relation "information_schema.sequences" does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, liquibase

I am trying to use liquibase to track my existing AWS redshift database. When I am trying to run the update, I get an error telling me that the information_schema.sequences is missing. It looks like it is not correctly speaking "redshift". I have included a version of my properties below.

```
❯ liquibase generate-changelog --changeLogFile="gen.sql"
####################################################
##   _     _             _ _                      ##
##  | |   (_)           (_) |                     ##
##  | |    _  __ _ _   _ _| |__   __ _ ___  ___   ##
##  | |   | |/ _` | | | | | '_ \ / _` / __|/ _ \  ##
##  | |___| | (_| | |_| | | |_) | (_| \__ \  __/  ##
##  \_____/_|\__, |\__,_|_|_.__/ \__,_|___/\___|  ##
##              | |                               ##
##              |_|                               ##
##                                                ##
##  Get documentation at docs.liquibase.com       ##
##  Get certified courses at learn.liquibase.com  ##
##  Free schema change activity reports at        ##
##      https://hub.liquibase.com                 ##
##                                                ##
####################################################
Starting Liquibase at 20:27:03 (version 4.20.0 #7837 built at 2023-03-07 16:25+0000)
Liquibase Version: 4.20.0
Liquibase Open Source 4.20.0 by Liquibase

Unexpected error running Liquibase: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
  - Caused by: ERROR: relation "information_schema.sequences" does not exist
```

liquibase.properties file

```
changeLogFile:report.changelog-root.xml
url:  jdbc:redshift://localhost:1234/project_name
username:  <<UserGoesHere>>
password:  <<Passy-McPasswordFace>> 
driver: com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver
classpath:  lib/liquibase-redshift-4.20.0.jar
```

The aws drivers and the liquibase extensions are installed both in the lib directory in "C:\Program Files\liquibase\lib" and in a sub directory ".\lib"